# VS Code integrated terminal variable cannot be resolved

Tags: visual-studio-code

About this setting in VS Code:

[image]

Is there any way I can use `${fileDirname}` to open in the current file's path if available, and if not, on the user home as a default? I just switched to Ubuntu from Windows and the behaviour of VSCode integrated terminal with this setting has been bothering me a lot; I can't open the terminal if I don't have a file currently open because it shows this error:

[image]

And without this setting it prompts me every time to "select current working directory for new terminal", which I also don't want. Ideally it would be great to open on ${fileDirname} if available, or else on the user home as default behaviour, and not throw an error or prompt me for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `${relativeFileDirname}` instead since the terminal is already setting the base path to the `${cwd}`. This works for me as you describe, opens to the current file directory otherwise defaults to the current working directory.

[image]

If VSCode can't find the `relativeFileDirname` there's another problem at hand.